# Epicor always attaching a file to a new job creation

Tags: epicorerp, epicor10, epicor

recently our epicor 10 installation has been attaching the same .pdf file automatically to every new job that is created in the system. Any ideas how to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part in question had the attachment added to it in the parts menu and as a result the attachment was following it everywhere.  Removed the attachment and the issue was resolved.